# Add Text to start of ListBox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I want to know how I can add `TextBox` text to the start of some of items in my `Listbox`. For example when I type **'Game 1'** in the TextBox it shows that at each timing like `Game 1: 00:00:00` and if I type **'Game 2'** It shows it like `Game 2: 00:00:00` .

I am using `VB.Net`, any help would be appreicated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `VB.net` then let's just say you want to change the last Item of your `Listbox` then you could have the code below:

```
  Dim itm As String = ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
  ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) = TextBox1.Text + itm
```

If you want the selected item from the `Listbox` is where the value of the Textbox will be added then you could use `SelectedIndex` property instead like:

```
 Dim itm As String = ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
 ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) = TextBox1.Text + itm
```

Comment: Is that not C# ? I'm using .NET

Comment: @user2665617 C# is one of the several languages (e.g. C#, VB.Net, F#) of .Net framework. Are you using VB.net then?

Comment: yeah sorry, I was unaware that C# was of .NET Framework. I am using VB.net

Comment: What you do mean exactly when you say it does not work? Does it throw an exception? Or do you mean to say it runs but it does not meet your requirement? Do you want to add the time as well aside from the value from the Texbox and the existing value from the ListBox? Let's say if your value in the listbox is 'Good' does it mean when I click  button for example it would become 'Game 1 0:0:0 Good'? Assuming that the value from the texbox is 'Game 1'?

Comment: Yes I want it to say 'Game 1: 00:00:00' for example. But Game 1 is written inside the Textbox.

Comment: Is the `00:00:00` in the `Listbox` already? Or is it added along with `Game 1` for example? You need to very clear in your requirements. Don't assume anything because remember this is not face-to-face and you cannot afford to assume that somebody thousand miles from you could understand what you are trying to convey. Be specific then and provide ample example in order for you to be help more appropriately.

Comment: 00:00:00 is example for time, the Timer which I have puts it in. When I press Q it makes an indent so I know to look back at that point.